# Create and label an appendix

Tags: tables, labels, appendix

I am writing my thesis and want to create more than one appendix. I want to name them Appendix A, B, etc. and want to label all the content the name of the appendix like (Table A.1)

```
 \appendix

\chapter*{Appendix A} 

\label{A} 

\begin{landscape}
   \caption{name of the table} \begin{table} the table ... \end{tabular}
   \end{table} \end{landscape}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE should help.

```
% apptabprob.tex  SE 552919

\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{name of the table} 
THE TABLE
\end{table}

\appendix

%\chapter*{Appendix A}
\chapter{An Appendix A}
\label{A}

%\begin{landscape}  % is undefined
\begin{table}
\caption{name of the table} 
THE TABLE
\end{table}
%\end{landscape}

\chapter{Another Appendix B}
\label{B}

%\begin{landscape}  % is undefined
\begin{table}
\caption{name of the table} 
THE TABLE
\end{table}
%\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

However, as you have not provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}` showing what you have done I have had to guess what you might have done. The code that you did show for the table is completely wrong.